# Appcelerator framework handling JSON differently

Tags: json, post, titanium, titanium-mobile

Does the Appcelerator framework handles JSON differently or Am I missing something easy?

Titanium json -

```
    var params = {
    user: {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    },
    commit: "Sign In"
};
```

producing this as a output -

```
 Parameters: {"user"=>"{email=123saurabhjain@gmail.com, password=96e79218965eb72c92a549dd5a330112}"}
```

But I need the output like this -

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"abcdefgh@gmail.com", "password"=>
FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

In the former output,

1) `email` and `password` fields are not in double quotes.

2) The assignment sign `=>` is not coming for the `email` and `password` fields.
   Instead I am getting the `=` sign for the fields.

What's going on here as my json seems to be correct ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var params= {
    user: {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    },
    commit: "Sign In"
};
```

Then send like this:

```
loginReq.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```